# Behavior of launching the same JAVA program twice ( at same time )

Tags: java

If I open up two command prompts and launch the same JAVA program in these 2 windows (at the same time ) , what would be its behaviour?

If they would remain distinct instance then how they are distinguished by JVM in terms of memory etc ?

This was asked in my interview and I replied that both running instance would be different since both would have different class loader . Was I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They run in distinct memory spaces for the same reason all other programs run in distinct memory spaces: That's how the OS runs them. You have to do something on purpose to get two different processes to share the same memory.

Assuming you're running them via the `java` tool, then more specifically, that's how the OS runs the `java` tool (which loads and initializes the JVM), which then loads and runs the program in its distinct memory area.

Your classloader answer is correct as far as it goes, because each JVM will have its own copy of the default classloader, but it's more fundamental than that: It's at the process level. Focussing on the classloader gives the impression that there's only one JVM running, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For every instance of  JVM  some free memory is allocated by OS, different memory for  each instance, this memory is then divided into some partitions like Stack, heap, miscellaneous and other.

When a class is loaded into JVM internal memory by class loader, it executes   static, field and instance initializers and allocates memory to variables, after   constructors are executed the object is created, and this process is repeated by   JVM every time when you invoke/run a program in a different command prompt.